# how to solve erorr "Unknown options: --zipfile, fileb://panda_layer.zips)" ? aws, layer, lambda

Tags: pandas, layer, cloud9

I have created "layer" for lambda function in cloud9, but i got error like this? how to solve this?

`$ aws lambda publish-layer-version --layer-name pandas-tutorial --zipfile fileb://panda_layer.zip --compatible-runtimes python3.9`

Note: AWS CLI version 2, the latest major version of the AWS CLI, is now stable and recommended for general use. For more information, see the AWS CLI version 2 installation instructions at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2.html

usage: aws [options]   [ ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

aws help
aws  help
aws   help

Unknown options: --zipfile, fileb://panda_layer.zip

Comment: Try this command: aws lambda publish-layer-version --layer-name pandas-tutorial --zip-file fileb://panda_layer.zip --compatible-runtimes python3.9

Answer (score 1):

Tobie van der Merwe's comment is correct. You passed the argument name `--zipfile` when it should be `--zip-file`.

I came across this issue after realizing I was passing `zip_file`.

In this case the error message really does help.